# Significance of dead body pose in yoga

Tags: yoga

My yoga instructor always asks me to finish off my session with the dead body pose. I understand the need and benefits of a cooling off session but when I'm hard pressed for time I sometimes skip it. Is there anything else that I'm missing? Is there any neurogical or other benefits that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your practice includes a proper cool-down sequence, then, by the end of your session, your heart rate, blood pressure, and breath rate should be close to their resting values already. So physiologically, no, you are not missing anything.

A longer stay in the dead body pose is recommended for deep relaxation, it is a form of meditation, a form of mindfulness. The reason for its inclusion at the end of yoga sequences is symbolic, to emphasize, that yoga is mental as well as physical training. Staying completely still is a challenge for many people. There is a lot of value in developing a meditative practice, including increased concentration, increased mental clarity. These skills are very useful especially when you are hard-pressed for time.

If you have time constraints, you could always let your instructor know that beforehand so she could help you and recommend how to organize and perhaps split your routine.

Answer (score 3):

Savasana or the Dead Body pose is a relaxation technique and to benefit from it you don't need to spend a long time in the pose.
This is from my personal experience,what you need to do is try to feel each and every part of the body from head to toe while taking deep breaths.

What this process does is it will relax your muscles by focusing your attention on that part, and when i say feel i mean mentally not by physically moving.You have to remain still.Do this for about 5 minutes. This was the technique i learned in school.I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Dead body pose is called as shavasana (corpse pose). (Corpse mean Shava)

It removes tiredness and enables the mind (and whole body) to relax. It is pose of relaxation and it is essential to practice this in between other asanas or after busy day.

This pose is necessary because there is a tendency to hold tension in some part. The wole body must relax, then the breathing will simultaneously slow down. Try to ignore the mental chatter and concentrate only on the breath and body.

It effects influence the physical as well as the psychological structure. It manages high BP, peptic ulcer, anxiety, hysteria, cancer and all psychosomatic diseases and neuroses. Even though it is a static pose it revitalize the entire system. So it is necessary. Skipping it will may result into lack of relaxation and concentration.

[Note - Reference of diseases and neuroses taken from book name as 'Hatha Yoga Pradipika' by yoga publication trust]